# Conditional pattern on input text in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, regex

I need to validate input type only in some cases with regex pattern. But when that fields is hidden , whole form isn't valid so I can't proceed. Is there a way that I can make pattern conditional

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="FileName" id="FileName" ng-model="FileName" ng-required="fileModalMode=='Rename' || fileModalMode=='Create'" pattern="^(\w+\.?)*\w+$">
```

So something like

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="FileName" id="FileName" ng-model="FileName" ng-required="fileModalMode=='Rename' || fileModalMode=='Create'" ng-pattern="fileModalMode=='Rename' || fileModalMode=='Create' ? '^(\w+\.?)*\w+$'">
```

Comment: What you really want> conditional ng-required or ng-pattern ?

Answer (score 0):

- The checks which you have written in ng-pattern and ng-required, you
  can move that into **onInt()**.
- Take variable and assign the condition to it. And use that variable
  in HTML.